# Primefaces: Build project gives errors

Tags: jsf, maven, jsf-2, build, primefaces

I tried to checkout PrimeFaces source codes from [here](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/)

But when i try to open it from it's pom.xml and building it gives 187 errors exactly like DataTable Class not found or Carousel... not found etc.

Comment: u need to specify some of the errors at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the sources in the directory where pom.xml is type:

```
mvn install
```

This should download the required dependencies, compile the sources and package the binaries. At the end you will see something like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 01 06:33:24 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/366M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```